# JOIN info from one table onto a UNION of two others... Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, union, inner-join

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM products as p, cat_index1 as c1, cat_index_2 as c2  
WHERE p.pid = c1.cid OR p.pid = c2.cid
```

not that I expected it to work, but EXPLAIN yields the following error:

```
Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const table...
```

I've got a list of products and a table for each category, I would like to pull info from more than one category at a time and join it with the product info. Products in the table products can be in both categories, one category or neither. The output needs to be a union of cat_index1 with cat_index2 and I want to join the info from products with said union.

The product table is pretty big, lots of info in there, but the category tables are a single column just containing the product ids of members of said category which are, of course, equal to the id column in the product table. No foreign keys are currently set.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use a union between cat_index tables and put it in join with the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT *  
FROM products as p
where 
EXISTS(select * from cat_index1 as c1 where p.pid = c1.cid) or  EXISTS(select * cat_index_2 as c2  
WHERE p.pid = c2.cid)
```

Comment: The OP also states that "Products can be in both categories, one category or neither.". This query will not return products in neither category.

Comment: or 1=1 is solution for product is not in categories.

Comment: Please take away the 'or 1=1'... you were right the first time. The query as edited, would not display anymore info than "SELECT * FROM products" nor would it filter any of the results. The extra select statements would be unnecessary.

Comment: @Troy Knapp: This is just more evidence that your question is unclear. He added `or 1=1` because you wrote "Products can be in both categories, one category or neither." What did you mean by that? Do you want this query to return products that have no associated cat_index record or not?

Comment: Andrej L's original answer was correct, since it has been edited AFTER I tested it, the new answer is incorrect. I'm taking away the check mark until it is fixed.

@Asaph, I'm done apologizing for wording my original question badly. Further complaining is not constructive, you COULD suggest changes to the syntax.

Comment: So I thought that you checked with or 1=1 and added this one to the main answer. It's not a problem for me by I don't like this approach with removing the best answer instead of reverting changes.

Comment: If you revert the change, then I will add the check mark again... I just didn't want someone stumbling upon this question in the meantime and thinking the answer as written now is correct. Furthermore, I didn't know how long it would take for you to make said changes, or even IF you would. If you change it, please comment and mention me, so I can make the correction as quickly as possible.

Comment: @troy-knapp see previous comments

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *  
FROM products as p
inner join cat_index1 as c1 on (p.pid = c1.cid)

union

SELECT *  
FROM products as p
inner join cat_index2 as c2 on (p.pid = c2.cid)
```

Comment: If he did this, he would have no way of telling records coming from `cat_index1` apart from records coming from `cat_index2`.

Comment: @Asaph: It suffices to add a field in both selects. select *,'tab1' as source_table ... union all select *,'tab2' ...

Comment: @nick rulez: There is another problem here. The OP also states that "Products can be in both categories, one category or neither.". This query will not return products in neither category.

Comment: @aseph. sorry for the confusion... if I wanted products in neither category and cat1 or cat2, I would just select from the product table. What I'm looking for is a UNION of cat1 and cat2 with the product info joined to said UNION. I'm running benchmarks now, and I'll vote for the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the results you described you desire, I think you're actually looking for an `OUTER JOIN`. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cat_index1 as c1 ON c1.cid = p.pid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cat_index2 as c2 ON c2.cid = p.pid
```

This query will return *all* the products and their associated records in `cat_index1` and `cat_index2`. If no matching record exists in `cat_index1` or `cat_index2`, you'll still have the products row included in your result set.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was misleading, as @Andrej L said, this is the logical equivalent of SELECT * FROM products, the joins would be unnecessary. I've edited the question to be more clear, please comment if you think the wording needs to change.

Comment: It's not the logical equivalent of `SELECT * FROM products` because the outer joins give you the `cat_index1` and cat_index2` data, which is presumably what you asked for. I think the fact that you got different interpretations of your question suggests that it was indeed worded confusingly. I suggest next time, instead of suggesting a solution (like how you suggested `UNION`), instead show some sample data and what your expected query output would be. Leave the details of the query up to the answerer.

Comment: As stated in the question originally, the cat indexes just held the product id's corresponding to the rows in table products. No original content is in them. 3 out of 4 responses were correct, so I don't think I was way out in left field. Regardless, I'll take your advice for my next question. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Troy Knapp: You need to take a closer look at these queries. They can't all be "correct" because they return different results. Look at the one you marked correct. The `or 1=1` part at the end of that query basically makes it return all rows in the `product` table. The one you marked correct returns the exact same result as `select * from products` but does so in a slower more roundabout way.

Comment: The 1=1 part was an edit after the check was awarded. I came back and put in the comment saying that his solution was the fastest, THEN I noticed that he had changed it, then I asked him to change it back (I don't have sufficient edit privileges to reverse his edit). The size of the product table is over 57k, you can see by the returned result when I benchmarked his answer that it returned the correct result. You are right though, after his edit, his answer was wrong. He hasn't changed it back yet (and my submitted edit hasn't been peer reviewed yet), so I'll go with another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using WHERE IN () and union cat_index1.cid and cat_index_2.cid:

```
SELECT * FROM Products AS P WHERE P.pid IN
(
SELECT cat_index1.cid
 UNION 
SELECT cat_index_2.cid
)
```

Comment: Ah you're right. He'd like to pull data from more than one category at a time.